Did people comment on Yukio Mishima's sexuality while he was alive?
Yukio Mishima had many run-ins with same-gender attraction:

He visited gay bars
His novel Confessions of a Mask has homosexual elements and is similar to his own life
His novel Forbidden Colors has homosexual elements

Did people speculate about his sexuality before his death in 1970?

Forbidden Colors was allegedly "touted as "an invitation to the world of homosexuality."" https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/books/98/10/25/specials/mishima-spring.html

Is this question exclusively about people's commentary, or if Yukio's self-declaration (if any) is included?

In The Homo Cultures of Iconic Personality in Japan: Mishima Yukio and Misora Hibari:

Specifically, the celebration in the homo magazines of two contemporary personalities illustrates divergent homo historical trajectories that
give insight into the ambiguities characterizing the male homosexual
experience in Japan. These are author and ultra-nationalist Mishima
Yukio (1925–1971)

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1057/9781137283788_7
I don't have access to the full chapter so I can't confirm when the "celebration" took place (before or after death).
Per shoover in the comments, these magazines started "after Mishima's death."
I found the article via this footnote:

I will review the arguments whether Mishima is a ‘gay writer’ or not later in this article. For fandom of Mishima Yukio as a gay icon among
Japanese gay community in the 1970s, see Mackintosh (2012).

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/374157940_mishima-yukio-and-the-homoeroticisation-of-the-emperor-of-japan-3891

"The Homo Cultures of Iconic Personality in Japan: Mishima Yukio and Misora Hibari" may be an article published separately, but the DOI links to a chapter by that name in a book called Idols and Celebrity in Japanese Media Culture, edited by Patrick W. Galbraith and Jason G. Karlin. The chapter mentions several magazines that started in the early 1970s, all of them after Mishima's death. Examples given of the "celebration in the homo magazines" are personal ads (M seeking M) that either quote one of the two personalities or profess an admiration for them. 1/2

"Contemporary" is being used for "around the same time" i.e. 1972-1974 ish. 2/2
(Feel free to edit into your answer.)
